# Automatic provisioning of xen in private cloud

Tags: virtualization, distributed-computing, xen

I am setting up private cloud for some experiments using xen as the hosting system. But I am faced with a problem for which I can't seem to get solutions.

I have to do some kind of automatic provisioning of VMs given the server load. Eg: if server of type A gets to lets say 60% load the cloud should spawn off another vm instance of the same type to distribute the load(using the netscalar).

Is there an opensource system that can help me or how do I go about developing scripts to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to live-migrate the VMs depending on the load of the host. You can use [OpenNebula](https://www.opennebula.org) to help you with this. You can use the advanced scheduler named Haizea with OpenNebula. 
While I've never tried this, but you can use this with ONE's APIs to create more VMs if a VM gets too much load.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://openstack.org/

It's opensourced.

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack and OpenNebula are already mentioned, there are two more IaaS open-source projects:

- [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com)
- [Nimbus](http://www.nimbusproject.org)

Answer (score 0):

use apache cloudstack, it is open-source and it has tight integration with netscalar Load Balancers and F5 Load balancers, check below link for Netscalar LB creation and VM creation. Rules can be set on these and new VMs ca be spanned based on Load.

https://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/api/apidocs-4.5/TOC_Root_Admin.html

Answer (score -1):

There is a Cloud platform called Nimbo that lets you do this and more out of the box... http://www.hcltech.com/cloud-computing/Nimbo/ .

Comment: is this Open source. I would like to have a product that's community supported and something that i can dig into rather than a proprietary software.